# Redefine number of columns depending on min-screen resolutions with columnizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm using [columnizer jQuery plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) to split my content into columns. Note that my website is responsive has a fluid width container. I've been calling different javascripts through based on minscreen resolutions of the window, same as CSS media queries work.

The minscreen functions as different breakpoints, which I'd like to use to change the number of columns that get defined in the options of the `columnize()` function.

This is one of the functions I'm using to create a breakpoint:

```
/* Min Screen 480
----------------------------------------------------------------*/
function minScreen480(){
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        if ($(window).width() >= 480) {
            // Set stuff here
        }else{
            // Remove stuff here
        }
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
}
```

I then run the function on `window.resize` like so:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    minScreen480();
}).trigger('resize');
```

And here's the columnize function itself:

```
$('.element').columnize({ columns: 2, lastNeverTallest: true });
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but it never seems work out correctly. I can't put the `columnize()` function inside of my `minScreen480()` function because `columnize()` is already built to adjust it's columns on resize. When I put it inside the `minScreen480()` function and it runs on `window.resize`, the columns start multiplying and it becomes a big mess.

Can anyone with more experience help me out?

Still havn't been able to come with a solution. Thought I'd edit to see if I can get some help. Thanks!

Comment: Check out [FooTable](http://themergency.com/footable/). Might be something you need.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Thanks for the suggestion, but FooTable is for something completely different. Columnizer splits up your existing content into columns. FooTable is for tabular data and controlling which columns you would like to show/hide.

Answer (score 4):

if this question is still actual:

about multiplying of columns, when resizing - That happened because columnizer has his own resize function, and to stop this effect - you should use columnizer option **buildOnce**

```
$('.element').columnize({ columns: 2, lastNeverTallest: true, buildOnce:true });
```

and to *recolumnize* , try to use unwrap:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 $(window).resize(function(){

    // remove all parent make by your jquery columnizer
    $('.column > *').unwrap();

    // re-initialize jQuery columnizer with 1 column

    $('.element').columnize({ columns: 1 });

 });

});
```

found it here http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/2179

Comment: Thanks iamTonio. I appreciate the help as I'm still struggling with this. The answer you've provided seems to get me slightly closer, but doesn't quite do the trick. It works in the sense that the columns are _recolumnized_ successfully,but because the script wraps various chunks of text in `<p>` tags, the content starts getting messy and formatted incorrectly. Any thoughts?

Comment: @norsewulf In addition to the above answer, but instead of using jQueries `unwrap()`, cache the original contents in a hidden element on the page. 
When resizing, overwrite the messy content with the cached content and (re)apply columnizer on that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this CSS3 solution by Tommi Kaikkonen [TYPESETTING RESPONSIVE CSS3 COLUMNS](http://www.kaikkonendesign.fi/columns/) while trying to tackle the same problem. I'm not sure what browsers you have to support, but this works beautifully in IE10+, Webkit and iOS.

> "css3 columns take content and divide it into columns based on either the column-width or column-count css-properties. The former inserts content into a dynamic number of columns with the width you gave it. The latter distributes content in identical height to the number of columns you gave it."

In his example, he's using the CSS3 attribute `column-width` to define the width of the columns, which allows for the number of columns to iterate dynamically horizontally, instead of using `column-count` to specify a number of columns, and allow the height to dynamically adjust as needed.

For my needs, I have a fixed amount of content, so I'll be using media queries and `column-count` to control the number of columns my content is contained in, based on the browser window size.

1. [CSS3 column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)
2. developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width (sorry, it's only letting me post two links)

Comment: Can you include a portion of the solution or at least an explanation of it in your answer, in case that link ever goes dead.